# Problemas na Autenticação JWT da Apple com PHP ( error invalid_client )

Tags: php, ios, openssl, apple

> Esta não é necessariamente uma pergunta, mas sim uma solução que quero
> compartilhar com a comunidade sobre um problema que tive recentemente
> e eu não consigo responder em outros tópicos por falta de pontuação.

**Case:** um aplicativo iOS com login pelo Apple ID e backend em PHP.

**Problema:** As bibliotecas do PHP que utilizam o OpenSSL para fazer a criação do JWT não suportam o algoritmo ES256 que a Apple usa por causa de uma limitação do próprio OpenSSL. Com isso a utilização de bibliotecas nativa dele causam o erro ***{"error":"invalid_client"}***

Answer (score 0):

**Solução:**

> Essa explicação é um complemento ao tutorial que existe em
> https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple
> . Se você não entender algo por favor pergunte pra eu esclareça e,
> caso necessário, corrija a resposta.

Primeiramente instalei o Ruby no servidor com a dependência do JWT. Nele criei o seguinte script:

```
require 'jwt'
require 'json'

key_file = '../configs/applekey_12345ABCDE.p8'
team_id = '12345ABCDE'
key_id = 'ABCDE12345'

client_id = 'br.com.myapp'

headers = {
  'kid' => key_id
}

ecdsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new IO.read key_file


claims = {
    'iss' => team_id,
    'iat' => Time.now.to_i,
    'exp' => Time.now.to_i + 15777000,
    'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
    'sub' => client_id,
}

token = JWT.encode claims, ecdsa_key, 'ES256', headers

File.write('native_token.txt', token)

client_id = 'br.com.myapp.signin'

claims = {
    'iss' => team_id,
    'iat' => Time.now.to_i,
    'exp' => Time.now.to_i + 12777000,
    'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
    'sub' => client_id,
}

token = JWT.encode claims, ecdsa_key, 'ES256', headers

File.write('legacy_token.txt', token)
```

O script acima cria dois arquivos distintos: o primeiro é para o login nativo (que é utilizado no iOS 13 e superior) e o outro é para o legado (do iOS 12 e inferiores, que ocorre via Webview).

Para que esses dois tipos de login ocorram o programador do app terá que cadastrar os dois nomes (o bundle id e o service id), onde o bundle id é usado para o native e o service id é para o legacy.

Ele está gerando códigos com 6 meses de validade, e uma CRON no servidor renova ele mensalmente, sobrepondo nos mesmos arquivos.

Uma vez gerados esses dois TXTs o PHP irá consumir eles para fazer a request para a Apple e, assim, buscar a informação do e-mail do usuário dessa forma:

```
function getUserData($code,$is_legacy){
        $key = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", file_get_contents('ruby/'.($is_legacy=='native'?'native':'legacy').'_token.txt'));
        $client_id = 'br.com.myapp'.($is_legacy=='native'?'':'.signin');            
        $data = array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'client_secret' => $key,
                    'code' => $code,
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
                    );
                    
        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array
        (
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data) );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        $serverOutput = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

        curl_close ($ch);

        $user_email = json_decode(base64_decode(explode('.',$serverOutput['id_token'])[1]),true)['email'];
        // FAÇA AQUI ALGO COM O $user_email 
}
```

Explicando em miúdos: $key recebe o conteúdo do arquivo gerado pelo script do Ruby através de um file_get_contents (considere que ele deve apontar para onde o TXT estiver). Ele pega o client_id de acordo com o tipo de autenticação e o $code que o app recebe quando a autenticação é autorizada. Então ele manda tudo pra Apple.

O retorno disso é um JSON que, dentro do objeto id_token, que nada mais é vários dados em base64 separados por pontos. Aqui basta pegar o objeto na segunda posição, "decriptar" ele e, com isso, obter o JSON com os dados onde o e-mail é, talvez, o único que realmente importe, já que o nome e sobrenome são entregues para o app assim que ele recebe a autorização (e o app deverá passar ele para o backend junto com o code para que você salve/atualize ele no seu banco de dados).